# Link en una imagen en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alguien me puede ayudar, en una ruleta tengo nombres de filosofos, cuando cae en alguno de ellos aparece la foto del filosofo pero quiero que al darle click a la foto me mande a otra pagina donde habrán preguntas como una trivia.
ayuda por favor es una especie de juego que entrego el lunes

```js
    var imagenes2da = new Array();
    imagenes2da[0] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/Tales de Mileto.png";
    
    imagenes2da[1] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/Anaximenes.png";
    
    imagenes2da[2] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/Heraclito.png";
    
    imagenes2da[3] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/empedocles.png";
    
    imagenes2da[4] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/Socrates.png";
    
    imagenes2da[5] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/platon.png";
    
    imagenes2da[6] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/epicuro.png";
    
    imagenes2da[7] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/ciceron.png";
    imagenes2da[8] = "c:/Users/Public/Documents/Videojuego Filosofos/img/marco.png";
    
    
     function getLink()
     {
        var l = document.getElementById("miLink");
         
         switch(imagenes2da){
          case 0:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Tales.html"; 
            break;
          case 1:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Anaximenes.html"; 
            break;
          case 2:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Heraclito.html"; 
            break;
          case 3:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Empedocles.html"; 
            break;
          case 4:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Socrates.html"; 
            break;
          case 5:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Platon.html"; 
            break;
          case 6:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Epicuro.html"; 
            break;
          case 7:
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Ciceron.html"; 
            break;
          case 8:
    
            document.getElementById("miLink").innerHTML = l.href = "Marco.html"; 
            break;
         }
         
    
     }
```

```html
<a  id="miLink"><img style"visibility:Hidden" src="img/ke.png" id="imgCarrusel" width="200px" height="300px" onclick="getLink()">
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que te podría recomendar hacer es tener un elemento que sea un `link` que dentro tenga una imagen o un `div` con una `img` y un `span` para el nombre del filosofo

```
<a id="linkRuleta" href="#"><div><img id="imagenRuleta"/ src="incognito"><span id="nombreRuleta">------</span></div></a>
```

Te recomiendo usar un array de objetos para tener el los tres elementos que necesitas a la mano:

```
var arrayFilosofos = [
{nombreFilosofo: nombre uno,
fotoFilosofo: foto-uno.png,
linkFilosofo: linkfilosouno.html}, 

{nombreFilosofo: nombre dos,
fotoFilosofo: foto-dos.png,
linkFilosofo: linkfilosodos.html}, 

...

{nombreFilosofo: nombre N,
fotoFilosofo: foto-N.png,
linkFilosofo: linkfilosoN.html}, 
]

Creas una funcion donde solo le pases por parametro el numero del filosofo y luego solo asignas a los elementos en html mediante javascript sus valores dentro del array de objetos

function seleccionarFilosoo(numeroFilosofo){

  document.getElementById("linkRuleta").href = arrayFilosofos[numeroFilosofo].linkFilosofo;
 document.getElementById("imagenRuleta").src = arrayFilosofos[numeroFilosofo].fotoFilosofo;
document.getElementById("nombreRuleta").innerHtml = arrayFilosofos[numeroFilosofo].nombreFilosofo;

}
```